# Silverlight: MVVM and re-initializing form

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, prism

We use Prism and from the grid we pop up a edit form that has two options, "Save" and "Save and New". My question is about re-initializing form. I am wondering if there is a better or simpler way? What I do is expose a InteractionRequest on the view model, and than use InteractionRequestTrigger in xaml to change the properties of the form, like this:

```
private void SubmitAndNewCommandCallback(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors)
{
    if (errors != null && errors.Any())
    {
        Errors = errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsNew)
        {
            _events.GetEvent<BidAgentCreated>().Publish(this.BidAgent);
        }

        _intializeFormRequest.Raise(this);
    } 
}


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding InitializeFormRequest}"  >
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="ctlAgentType" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="ctlAgentSearchBox" PropertyName="Text" Value=""/>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way is to get rid of the logic in your View and keep it in the ViewModel.

in xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AgentTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgentType,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

in the ViewModel

```
private void SubmitAndNewCommandCallback(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors)
{
    if (errors != null && errors.Any())
    {
        Errors = errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsNew)
        {
            _events.GetEvent<BidAgentCreated>().Publish(this.BidAgent);
        }

        SearchText="";
        SelectedAgentType = AgentTypes.First();  //selects first agenttype, or set to null to select nothing in the combobox

    } 
}
```